# Need fixed column widths in an emailed SQL server HTML table

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, outlook

I'm formatting SQL server query output into an HTML table that's emailed to Outlook using the sp_send_dbmail stored procedure. The problem is that the "table style="table-layout:fixed" and "td width="xx"" properties are ignored, and column widths vary depending on the content of data present in the first row (not the header titles). The following output shows this distortion (most readily visible in Column 4):

[Column Widths for Person 1's Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esFMn.png)

vs.

[Column Widths for Person's 2 Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYRW.png)

Printing @body_with_data2 within SQL server results in the following HTML output:

```
<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;">
  <html>
  <head>
    <style>
      td {
        border: solid black 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        font-size: 11pt;
      }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">Title Person Name 2</div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;">
      <table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
        <tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>
          <td width="60" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="375" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 5 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 6 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 7 Header Name</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor=#EEEEF4>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri"><a href="http://linktoIDs.com/7604/">7604</a></font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Person 1</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">01/01/2017</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description Test Description Test Description</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri"></font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description 2</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description 3</font></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
</div>
```

Viewing the source HTML code of the associated Outlook email does vary slightly:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;"><html><head><style>td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} </style></head><body><div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">Title Person Name 2</div><div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;"><table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr bgcolor="#4b6c9e"><td width="60" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="120" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="120" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="375" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="175" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 5 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="175" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 6 Header Name</b></font></td><td width="175" align="center"><font face="calibri" color="White"><b>Column 7 Header Name</b></font></td></tr><tr bgcolor="#EEEEF4"><td align="center"><font face="calibri"><a href="http://linktoIDs.com/7604/">7604</a></font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri">Test Person 1</font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri">01/01/2017</font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri">Test Description Test Description Test Description</font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri"></font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri">Test Description 2</font></td><td align="center"><font face="calibri">Test Description 3</font></td></tr></table></div></body></html></div>
```

Removing width="100%" does not solve the issue. The associated HTML output is lsited below:

```
<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;"><html><head><style>
td {
border: solid black 1px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
padding-top:1px;
padding-bottom:1px;
font-size:11pt;
}
</style></head><body>
<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">Title Person Name 2</div>
<div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;">
  <table style="table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
    <tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>
      <td width="60" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="375" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 5 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 6 Header Name</b></font></td>
      <td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 7 Header Name</b></font></td>

      </tr>
      <tr bgcolor=#EEEEF4>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri"><a href="http://linktoIDs.com/7604/">7604</a></font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Person 1</font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri">01/01/2017</font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description</font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri"></font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description 2</font></td>
        <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description 3</font></td>

      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any advice on on how to set column widths to a pre-defined size would be be much appreciated. The relevant portion of the query is copied below.

```
IF(EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM #TEMP2))
            BEGIN

                set @textTitle = 'Title'+@PERSON_NAME

                set @body_with_data2 = '<html><head><style>' +
                   'td {border: solid black 1px;padding-left:5px;padding-right:5px;padding-top:1px;padding-bottom:1px;font-size:11pt;} ' +
                   '</style></head><body>' +
                   '<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">' +
                   @textTitle + '</div>' +
                   '<div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;"><table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>' +
                   '<tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>' +
                   '<td width="60" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td>' +    
                   '<td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td>' +    
                   '<td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td>' +    
                   '<td width="375" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td>' +     
                   '<td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 5 Header Name</b></font></td>' +    
                   '<td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 6 Header Name</b></font></td>' +    
                   '<td width="175" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 7 Header Name</b></font></td></tr>'   

                set @body=''
                select @body =
                (
                   select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by [ID]) % 2 as TRRow,
                           td = CAST('<a href="' + 'http://linktoIDs.com/' + CAST([ID] AS varchar(10)) + '/">'+CAST([ID] AS varchar(10))+'</a>' AS XML), 
                           td = [Col_2_Data],      
                           td = [Col_3_Data],      
                           td = [Col_4_Data],     
                           td = [Col_5_Data],     
                           td = [Col_6_Data],     
                           td = [Col_7_Data]      
                  FROM #TEMP2
                  ORDER BY [ID] DESC

                   for XML raw('tr'), elements
                )

                set @body = REPLACE(@body, '<td>', '<td align=center><font face="calibri">')
                set @body = REPLACE(@body, '</td>', '</font></td>')
                set @body = REPLACE(@body, '_x0020_', space(1))
                set @body = Replace(@body, '_x003D_', '=')
                set @body = Replace(@body, '<tr><TRRow>0</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#F8F8FD>')
                set @body = Replace(@body, '<tr><TRRow>1</TRRow>', '<tr bgcolor=#EEEEF4>')
                set @body = Replace(@body, '<TRRow>0</TRRow>', '')

                set @body_with_data2 = @body_with_data2 + @body + '</table></div></body></html>'

                set @body_with_data2 = '<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;">' + @body_with_data2 + '</div>'

            END
```

Comment: If you could provide an example of the output HTML, that would be helpful

Comment: Jon P, thanks for the response! See the images in my updated question above. Excluding the link in Column 1, all row data below the header names consists of text.

Comment: The HTML **code** is what we're after. The images are helpful, the HTML will be more so.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jon P. The question has been updated accordingly. Please note I included HTML generated by SQL as well as the code present in Outlook.

Comment: OK, we're slowly getting there, next questions is why is the whole lot including you're `html` node wrapped in a div? That's invalid html for a start.

Answer (score 0):

You can use td style width, max-width and min-width for the email body.

```
<td style="width:100px;max-width:100px;min-width:100px">&nbsp;</td>
```

> In general, max-width overrides width, but min-width overrides max-width.

Comment: Thanks Amit. I tried applying the max/min td style width, but it did not resolve the issue. For reference, I replaced "<td width="xx" align=center><font face...." with "<td style="width:100px;max-width:100px;min-width:100px" align=center>&nbsp;<font face...." for all 7 column headers.

Answer (score 0):

From the MDN Doc on [table-layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout)

> Table and column widths are set by the widths of `table` **and** `col` elements or by the width of the first row of cells. Cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

Emphasis mine.

You have a table width of 100%, so the table is going to expand to fill the available space. You can't have this **and** fixed column widths. If you remove `width="100%"` you should be fine.

See the examples below, I've truncated the table to emphasise the point.

```css
td {
        border: solid black 1px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        padding-bottom: 1px;
        font-size: 11pt;
      }
```

```html
<h2>Width 100%</h2>
    <div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">Title Person Name 2</div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;">
      <table style="table-layout:fixed;" width="100%" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
        <tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>
          <td width="60" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="375" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor=#EEEEF4>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri"><a href="http://linktoIDs.com/7604/">7604</a></font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Person 1</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">01/01/2017</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description Test Description Test Description</font></td>
          
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

<h2>No Width</h2>

<div style="margin-top:20px; margin-left:5px; margin-bottom:15px; font-weight:bold; font-size:1.3em; font-family:calibri;">Title Person Name 2</div>
    <div style="margin-left:5px; font-family:Calibri;">
      <table style="table-layout:fixed;" cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0>
        <tr bgcolor=#4b6c9e>
          <td width="60" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 1 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 2 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="120" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 3 Header Name</b></font></td>
          <td width="375" align=center><font face="calibri" color=White><b>Column 4 Header Name</b></font></td>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor=#EEEEF4>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri"><a href="http://linktoIDs.com/7604/">7604</a></font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Person 1</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">01/01/2017</font></td>
          <td align=center><font face="calibri">Test Description Test Description Test Description</font></td>
          
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Removing width="100%" did not solve this issue either. I've updated the question to include the associated HTML output. Any thoughts on what else can be tried?

Comment: From using your output here : https://jsfiddle.net/6mmkhLpf/ it still seems to work as expected. NOTE: The table will only use available space first, so unless the viewport is 1284px or more wide the cells will be scaled to best fit the width. You could always set a width on the table of 1284px to force the table to that width. Also remove the outermost div that wraps the `html` node

Comment: I removed the div that wraps the HTML node and set the table width to 1284x per your jsfiddle example. These steps do normalize the column widths when entering the HTML output into jsfiddle, but unfortunately the problem still exists when viewing the tables in Outook. Perhaps this is an issue with Outlook? I believe the div that wraps the HTML node is the following but please let me know if I should remove something else: "set body_with_data2 = '<div style="color:Black; font-size:11pt; font-family:Calibri; width:100px;">' + body_with_data2 + '</div>'".

Comment: That looks like the right div to remove. Email clients are notoriously difficult when it comes to styling, so it could well be outlook. Tables are generally handled OK by email clients so this is somewhat surprising.